# Vue 2 - change model in main instance from the component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following component:

```
Vue.component('visible-filter', {
    template: `
        <span class="text-muted"
            @mouseenter="changeClassMouseenter($event)"
            @mouseout="changeClassMouseout($event)"
            @click="countryTest(filter)"
            @clicked="clicked = true"
            v-model="clicked"
        ><slot></slot></span>
    `,

    props: ['filter', 'clicked'],

    methods: {

        changeClassMouseenter(event) {
            console.log(this.clicked);
            event.target.classList.remove('text-muted')
        },

        changeClassMouseout(event) {
            event.target.classList.add('text-muted')
        },

        countryTest(filter) {
            Event.$emit('clicked');
            Event.$emit('country-filter', filter);
        }
    }

});
```

The Event in the main instance:

```
Event.$on('clicked', () => {
    this.clicked = true;
})
```

The data in the main instance:

```
data: {
    clicked: false
},
```

The thing I want to do:

When I click on the element, I want to set the **clicked** property to true (for that element), and for the rest of the elements I want to set it to false; Also I want to check if the **clicked** is true/false when the **mouseenter/mouseout** event is fired.

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not change the parent from child.
2. To make communication between parent and child (and child->parent as well) you can/should set up the events.
3. Emit the event in child component. Nice examples here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events
4. Listen to event in your parent using `<child-component @yourEventName='eventHandler(data)'>`
5. Handle data in your parent, so add `eventHandler(data)` into your methods and do whatever you want with your data.